# Why are $i$ and $-i$ "more indistinguishable" than $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Today I learned that two roots of an irreducible polynomial are "algebraically indistinguishable."

In $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, define the conjugate of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ as $\overline{a+b\sqrt{2}} = a - b\sqrt{2}$.

My understanding/intuition on "algebraically indistinguishable" is that if $P$ and $Q$ are algebraic expressions (meaning using the ring operations only) in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ with $P$ = $Q$, then then we also have $\overline{P} = \overline{Q}$ where $\overline{P}$ and $\overline{Q}$ are the algebraic expressions $P$ and $Q$ except every member of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ in the expression is replaced with its conjugate.

For example,

$2(3+\sqrt{2})(4+\sqrt{2}) - (6-\sqrt{2}) = 22 + 15\sqrt{2}$

and indeed,

$2(3-\sqrt{2})(4-\sqrt{2}) - (6+\sqrt{2}) = 22 - 15\sqrt{2}$.

And in $\mathbb{R}(i) = \mathbb{C}$, we're guaranteed the same phenomenon:

$2(3+i)(4+i) - (6-i) = 16 + 15i$

$2(3-i)(4-i) - (6+i) = 16 - 15i$

But what I find interesting is that once I involve familiar operations outside of multiplication and addition, this will no longer hold for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, but it still holds for $\mathbb{R}(i) = \mathbb{C}$.

For example,
$(-\sqrt{2})^{-\sqrt{2}} \neq \overline{\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}}$
while on the other hand,$(-i)^{-i} = \overline{i^{i}}$.

My initial answer to this is that exponentiation viewed as a binary operation is not closed in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, so I must view this as an operation on $\mathbb{R}(i) = \mathbb{C}$, but this is a larger field than extending $\mathbb{Q}$ to include the roots of $x^{2}-2$, so in this field with exponentiation, I can now distinguish $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$. On the other hand, exponentiation on $\mathbb{R}(i) = \mathbb{C}$ is closed, so even exponentiation does not allow us to algebraically distinguish between $a+bi$ and $a-bi$.

Comment: First of all, $z^w$ is not well-defined for general complex numbers $z,w$, so your equality is questionable. Now you can argue that the logarithm is well defined on, say $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{-}$, and so your equation still makes sense. But then the difference is that exponentiation is no longer an "algebraic operation" in the sense that it's not definable from the language of fields. In particular, it shouldn't be surprising that it behaves badly wrt conjugates. You could similarly define arbitrary operations that behave badly on conjugates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is such a good question!$\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$

**My first answer:** Let's give a definition of what it means for two elements of a field to be algebraically indistinguishable over a base field. Let $K/L$ be a field extension, and let $\alpha,\beta \in K$. We say
$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraically indistinguishable in $K$ over $L$ if there is an automorphism of $K$ over $L$, $\phi$, such that $\phi(\alpha)=\beta$. (Since any automorphism of a field fixes the characteristic subfield, we will say that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraically indistinguishable in $K$ if they are algebraically indistinguishable over the characteristic subfield. Since our base field is $\QQ$, which is the characteristic subfield, we'll therefore drop the "over $\QQ$" language).

What does this mean? Well it means that for any polynomial expression in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $L$, say $p(\alpha)$, then $\phi(p(\alpha))=p(\phi(\alpha))$.

Now because $\QQ(\sqrt{2})$ has an automorphism (conjugation) over $\QQ$ that sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are algebraically indistinguishable in $\QQ(\sqrt{2})$. Similarly $\QQ(i)$ also has an automorphism sending $i$ to $-i$. So $i$ and $-i$ are algebraically indistinguishable in $\QQ(i)$.

Now what if we start taking larger fields? Are $i$ and $-i$ still algebraically indistinguishable as elements of $\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}\CC$? Yes! Conjugation is also an automorphism of $\CC$.

How about $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$? Are they algebraically indistinguishable in $\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}\RR$? in $\CC$? The answer might be a little odd. Note that $\sqrt{2}$ is real, and implicit in our notation is an assumption that $\sqrt{2}$ is positive, and that $-\sqrt{2}$ is negative. Over $\QQ(\sqrt{2})$, we can't tell the difference between the positive and negative square root, but over $\RR$ we can. Every positive element of $\RR$ has a square root in the field, but no negative element does. Thus there cannot be an automorphism $\phi$ of $\RR$ taking $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$, since if we had $u^2=\sqrt{2}$, then we would have to have $\phi(u)^2 = -\sqrt{2}$, which is impossible. Thus we can distinguish them over $\RR$.

However, over $\CC$, we now have all the square roots we could want, and since there is an automorphism of $\QQ(\sqrt{2})$ taking $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$, this can be extended to an automorphism of $\CC$ taking $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$ via general facts about algebraic closures. So now in $\CC$ we once again cannot distinguish $\QQ(\sqrt{2})$ and $\QQ(-\sqrt{2})$.

**My second answer (or rather a continuation):** But wait! We're working with $\RR$ and $\CC$! We have a topology. We can talk about other operations than just finite combinations of addition, multiplication and division! So we can define a notion of topologically indistinguishable elements. Let's say that two elements $\alpha,\beta$ of a topological field $K$ of characteristic 0 are *topologically indistinguishable* if there is a *continuous* field automorphism $\phi : K\to K$ such that $\phi(\alpha)=\beta$.

From this we get expressions like $\phi(e^\alpha)=e^{\phi(\alpha)} = e^\beta$. More concretely, we know that conjugation from $\CC\to \CC$ is continuous and $\bar{i}=-i$, so by our definition $i$ and $-i$ are topologically indistinguishable. Thus for any expression defined in terms of limits, addition, and multiplication, $F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, 
$$\overline{F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)} = F(\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\ldots,\bar{x_n}).$$
Thus we have $\overline{e^i} = e^{\bar{i}}$.
Now there's a slight complication with the $i^i$ expression, in that $\log i$ is not really well defined. However, for any $w$ such that $e^w = i$, $e^{\bar w} = \bar{i}$, so for any such choice of $w$, $\overline{i^i} =\overline{e^{wi}}= e^{\overline{w}\overline{i}} =\bar{i}^{\bar{i}}$, where the equalities there are really sketchy, since $i^i$ isn't *exactly* well defined. The central equality is the main point.

So $i$ and $-i$ are topologically equivalent, but what about $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ in $\CC$?

Well, to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ cannot be topologically equivalent, we just have to find an expression built out of limits, sums, products and divisions on which they differ. One example is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (x-1)^n.$$ 
For the positive square root of 2, this expression converges to 0, and for the negative square root of 2 this diverges. Hence there cannot be a continuous field automorphism sending one to the other, since then all such expressions would have to either converge on both $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ or diverge on both.

Thus $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are not topologically indistinguishable.

This I believe is the source of what you're observing. Both $\pm i$ and $\pm\sqrt{2}$ are algebraically indistinguishable in $\CC$, but $i$ and $-i$ are also topologically indistinguishable in $\CC$, but $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are not.

Comment: I think you meant to write $u^2 = 2$ and $\phi(u)^2 = -2$

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg I do not, I mean that $u$ is a square root of the positive square root of 2.

Comment: I see, sorry! ${}{}{}$

Comment: Nice, thoughtful answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! My professor did mention the topology of R and C when I (tried to) ask this question but an in-depth explanation would have been very tangential to the lecture.

Comment: @JonathanHebert Np, glad it was helpful :)

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks! :)